# "Failed loading ClientOU certificate at ..." while running a Hyperledger Fabric sample "Building Your First Network"

Tags: shell, windows-10, hyperledger-fabric, backslash, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to test my development environment and keep getting this error while going through the "Building Your First Network". I've installed the prerequisites on a Windows 10 Home edition so I'm using Docker Toolbox. The error is described as follows and happens just after a execute the `./byfn.sh up -l node` command:

> 2019-11-14 17:06:26.982 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> INFO 002 Failed loading ClientOU certificate at [/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem]: [could not read file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.example.com-cert.pem: no such file or directory]

As you can see there is a backslash just before the `ca.example.com-cer.pem` which I think is causing the problem. Anyone have an idea of how I might solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution? I'm struggling with the same problem and I'm running under Container Optimized OS on Google Cloud, so this backslash is not a problem of Docker under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Docker Toolbox for windows doesn't provide a great experience for users. It's limited in how it can share windows directories with linux containers running in the linux VM it creates. I believe it can be made to work but you have to use very specific folders in your home directory and you would have to google it to find all the details but it's a lot more of a hassle.
You have other options of course

1. Upgrade to Windows Pro and use Docker for Windows (which doesn't have the same sharing limitations, but still not a great experience and you can still encounter problems sharing the directories)
2. Install a hypervisor such as virtualbox and run a linux desktop distribution such as ubuntu or mint and use that instead (which I would recommend and would suggest ubuntu 18.04 mate edition)
3. Wait until next year when hopefully microsoft will release WSL2 for everyone (including home edition) and then Docker won't need a linux VM running and it should be a much better experience trying to run linux containers on windows.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by lindluni here
[Backslash problem in Hyperledger 2.0.1 when orderer/peer look for .pem files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60652529/backslash-problem-in-hyperledger-2-0-1-when-orderer-peer-look-for-pem-files)
the problem arises when one creates crypto artifacts under Windows since "golang `filepath.Join` uses the current OS's filepath scheme". Hence, under Windows backslash is used in all the generated config.yaml files found in crypto-config/*. One can replace this backslashes before the deployment to fix the issue.