# Backslash problem in Hyperledger 2.0.1 when orderer/peer look for .pem files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hyperledger-fabric, pem

I'm trying to deploy a Hyperledger 2.0.1 Network with 3 orgs, 2 peers per org and 5 RAFT orderers. All this in GCP under Container optimized OS.
On my orderer nodes I observe the following Warnings:

```sh
2020-03-12 09:44:41.684 UTC [msp] loadCertificateAt -> WARN 007 Failed loading OrdererOU certificate at [/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.industrial-cert.pem]: [could not read file /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.industrial-cert.pem: open /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/cacerts\ca.industrial-cert.pem: no such file or directory]
```

The problem has obviously to do with the wrong slash `msp/cacerts\ca.industrial-cert.pem`. The file is there on the node and is accessible. Here is a part of docker-compose file:

```yaml
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.0.1
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt,/var/hyperledger/peers/tls/ca_1.crt,/var/hyperledger/peers/tls/ca_2.crt,/var/hyperledger/peers/tls/ca_3.crt]
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
      - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
```

Is this a bug, or I miss anything?

Comment: The backslash is coming from the`configuration.NodeOUs.OrdererOUIdentifier.Certificate` value in `/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/config.yaml` can you exec into the container and take a look at what that entry is. I took a look at our code, and the only way this would happen is if the slash already existed in the config.yaml file

Comment: Thank you! That's the case. So the problem arises, when I create artifacts under Windows but then deploy everything under linux.

Comment: That's 100% the problem. golang `filepath.Join` uses the current OS's filepath scheme. So it used the windows slash scheme to join the two pre-existing strings. Glad it was easy to uncover the problem, not always the case

Comment: Just a remark. Some of the config.yaml files are generated with correct slashes. In my case e.g. :
peerOrganizations/org2/msp/config.yaml is correct
peerOrganizations/org2/peers/peer0.org2/msp/config.yaml is incorrect 
Meaning the files are generated with different logic.